# How can i make this button on React.js with Material UI or other tool?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, button, material-ui

I want to make a button similiar as this image. I think is composed by a button (left side) i dont know how i can make the right side of it (the arrow figure) and inside the arrow is an image and a Typography i guess. Hope you can help me!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed like that, you create your button component and you format it with css, you create the tip of the arrow with a pseudo element.

```js
const App = () => {

  const icon1 = "https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/crane.png"
  const icon2 = "https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/30/000000/interstate-plow-truck.png"
  
  const ArrowButton = ( props ) => (
    <div className="arrow_box" onClick={props.click} >
    <div className="arrow_button"></div>
    <div className="arrow_content">
      <div className="arrow_content_img-box">
      <img className="arrow_content_img" alt="icon" src={props.icon} />
      </div>
      <span className="arrow_content_text">{props.iconRef}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  )

  const handleClick = () => {
    alert('click')
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1 className="title__primary">Arrow Button</h1>
      <ArrowButton icon={icon1} iconRef={"pl001"} click={handleClick} />
      <ArrowButton icon={icon2} iconRef={"fr005"} click={handleClick} />
    </div>
  );
};

    ReactDOM.render(
      <App />, document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.arrow_box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: 2px solid #c9cdd0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #c9cdd0;
  border-left: 2px solid #c9cdd0;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.arrow_box::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 89.5%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 2px solid #c9cdd0;
  border-right: 2px solid #c9cdd0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-top: -21px;
}

.arrow_box:hover, .arrow_box:hover::before{
  background-color: #006eff;
}

.arrow_button {
  position: relative;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #00122c;
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.arrow_button::before {
  content: "\2716";
}

.arrow_content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 56px;
  width: 144px;
}

.arrow_content_img-box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffe8aa;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.arrow_content_img {
  height: 35px;
  width: auto;
  filter: invert(75%) sepia(32%) saturate(7078%) brightness(100%)
    hue-rotate(15deg) contrast(100%);
}

.arrow_content_text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just divide the element in 3 divs: two rectangles and the triangle shape. Left rectangle - button with an icon in it, right rectangle - image and text and the triangle just an empty div. That's the style you can give to a div to make it looking like the triangle you need.

```
triangle: {
 width: 0,
 height: 0,
 backgroundColor: "transparent",
 borderStyle: "solid",
 borderLeftWidth: 50,
 borderRightWidth: 50,
 borderBottomWidth: 100,
 borderLeftColor: "transparent",
 borderRightColor: "transparent",
 borderBottomColor: "red",
 transform: "rotate(90deg)" }
```

[division](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or11H.png)